# How to mock mongoose schema using typescript and jest, what type to use for return?

Tags: typescript, mongoose

What should be the type for the object acting as the response for mongoose?

This is my mongoose mode/schema

```
import { model, Schema, Document } from "mongoose";

export interface ILocation extends Document{
  name: string;
  description: string;
}

const schema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
});

export const Location = model<ILocation>(process.env.DB_CONTAINER || "Null", schema)

export default Location
```

I then have a create record method, like so,

```
const createRecord = async (
  obj: ILocation,
  model: IModel
): Promise<Response> => {
  try {
    const response = await model.create(obj);
    return { code: 201, data: response };
  } catch (error) {
    return errorHandler(error);
  }
};
```

This is fine, everything is working, but now I need to mock the response for a uunit test and I cant pass any object in as the fake response without TypeScript errors.

e.g.

```
const dummyRecord: ILocation = {
  name: "name",
  description: "description",
};

Location.create(dummyRecord);

// is missing the following properties increment, model and 54 more.ts
```

What should be the type for the dummy record or the model so that the return type can be my schema?